# Sound popping and static audio Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 21.10

I just recently upgraded to 21.10 and i hear a pop sound from my speakers when i  boot into ubuntu.

I also experience loud static noise when listening to something on spotify or youtube which continues even after closing them and muting speakers. Ony way to fix it is to log out or restart my laptop.

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be pulseaudio related problem. Had the same on my MIIX-310.
Try to install pipewire-pulse and reboot. Worked for me at least.